# setAttribute in JavaScript not working with oraSearch

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in ORMB and have an input element like this

```
<input id="charVal" class="oraInput" oraField="charVal">
```

I want to dynamically add an oraSearch attribute using Javascript but it's not working

```
document.getElementById("charVal").setAttribute("oraSearch","CM_SR_CHAR");
```

Though if I try with other attributes, it's working fine. Also if I add the oraSearch statically like below, then also it's working

```
<input id="charVal" class="oraInput" oraField="charVal" oraSearch="CM_SR_CHAR">
```

Comment: There is no such attribute in HTML. I assume it is an expando attribute which has failed to use the data- prefix and is being read by JavaScript. You need to run your JavaScript **before** the JavaScript that looks for it.

Comment: run which JS before which JS??

Comment: "Your JS" = The JS you put in your question. "the JavaScript that looks for it" = whatever JavaScript is also in the page that reads that attribute, I don't know what JavaScript that is, but it must exist because nothing else is going to do anything with the attribute.

Comment: … unless the non-standard attributes are processed server side, in which case JS can't solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the DOM path for the JavaScript code.

I tried to put the script from the `<head>` and it didn't work, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("charVal").setAttribute("oraSearch","CM_SR_CHAR");
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input id="charVal" class="oraInput">


</body>
</html>
```

But, if you put it in the body, it works fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<input id="charVal" class="oraInput">
<script>
document.getElementById("charVal").setAttribute("oraSearch","CM_SR_CHAR");
console.log(document.getElementById("charVal"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: if you are taken the script from another file put the `<script></script>` inside the `<body>`